# How to set up firebase function in flutter web project

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

I am trying to configure the firebase real-time database in my flutter web project is there any suggestion for me to config the firebase real-time database in flutter web project?

https://pub.dev/packages/firebase#-installing-tab-
I have followed the above link to config the firebase libraray but how can I use the firebase real-time data base function?

Comment: Are you trying to use real-time database or firestore?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a helper class to init your database

```
import 'package:firebase/firebase.dart' as fb;

class FirebaseHelper {
  static fb.Database initDatabase() {
    try {
      if (fb.apps.isEmpty) {
        fb.initializeApp(
          apiKey: "add_your_own",
          authDomain: "add_your_own",
          databaseURL: "add_your_own",
          projectId: "add_your_own",
          messagingSenderId: "add_your_own",
        );
      }
    } on fb.FirebaseJsNotLoadedException catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    return fb.database();
  }
}
```

Then use it as follow

```
// global variable, not the best 
Database database = FirebaseHelper.initDatabase();

void main() {
  runApp(FirebaseApp());
}
```

Then in your widget use

```
 var databaseRef = database.ref("my_database").child("my_data");
```